# Get date format as "DD-MM-YYYY"

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetimepicker

I would like to get my date format as "DD-MM-YYYYY".

I tried adding in my code this way but it got error as **date.getFullYear is not a function**

```
var selectedDate = $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' }).val();
```

Below is my working code but the date format is come out like this:
               **firstDay : Wed May 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)

lastDay  : Fri May 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)**

```
var selectedDate = $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker('getDate');

var date = selectedDate, y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);                             
$("[id$=txtFirstDate]").val(firstDay)
$("[id$=txtEndDate]").val(lastDay)
```

Comment: What's with this `$("[id$=datepicker]")`. I think this is wrong.

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: You need to parse date using `Date()` before using `date.getFullYear`

Comment: @DeepakSingh : it [means](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) *select all elements with id ending with 'datepicker'*

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg well this was new to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **getFullYear** with dategormat code the use like this:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
        day  = date.getDate(),  
        month = date.getMonth() + 1,              
        year =  date.getFullYear();
    date = day + '-' + month + '-' + year
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' }).val();

day  = selectedDate.getDate(),  
month = selectedDate.getMonth() + 1,              
year =  selectedDate.getFullYear();
```

This Will work